# Completely import a module into current scope

Tags: scope, pascal, freepascal

Say I have 2 Units, `MainUnit`, and `ExampleClass`.

MainUnit:

```
Unit MainUnit;

interface

Uses ExampleClass;

function ReturnFive: Integer;

implementation

function ReturnFive: Integer;
begin
  ReturnFive := 5;
end;

begin
end.
```

ExampleClass:

```
Unit ExampleClass;

{$mode objfpc}

interface

type 
  ClassThing = Class
    SampleValue: Integer;
  end;
  

implementation

begin
end.
```

Now, I'd like to only import `MainUnit`, but still be able to use `ClassThing`. `MainUnit` `uses ExampleClass`, but `ClassThing` isn't usable when you import `MainUnit`.

I don't really want to just `use` `ExampleClass` along with `MainUnit`, I'd prefer to keep it in one `uses` statement.

How do you do this?

Comment: You can't. But you don't have to *use* MainUnit if you only need to access ClassThing of course.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz So you just have to pack everything into one file, or use a bunch of different modules? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put

```
type ClassThing = ExampleCLass.ClassThing;
```

in the interface of mainunit.

The principle also works for consts, but only "real" ones (not typed ones which are more initialized vars):

```
const myconst = unitname.myconst;
```

Nearly all my much used types are similar aliases, so that I can easily move around where they are defined without changing the uses clause in all the businesscode units